# How can I create a wipe transition effect in Figma like in the link?

Tags: animation, figma

[Wipe effect animation sample](https://li.ki/waitinglist-1)

[My Animation in Figma](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1311441737928852096/wip-wipe-transition-animation-0-7)

Moving mask is the solution.

I need it for Lottie animation. I also used opacity for the slider like in the sample. I made that as an interactive component to finish the opacity effect in one second. But the the problem is that Lottie files do not support Figma components.
Now I don’t how to stop opacity in one second using frames!

I tried to use subframes but then there was no option of delay. I tried to use multiple frames but Lottie plugin takes one flow at a time.

So how can I have multiple animation effects in Figma for Lottie files?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hello Waqas. I'm under the impression you're trying to ask multiple questions in one. Could you [edit] your question to give it more focus?

Comment: `Wipe effect animation sample` link not working - 404.